# Is there any way to invert Y axis when using an xbox controller on PC

Tags: lego-marvel-super-heroes

I've tried to go in the option menu and switch the *look up/down* controls but it doesnt seem to change anything. Is there any way to invert the Y axis ? It would be helpful especially when trying to lock up target with the cursor.

Answer (score -1):

No. Can't do it. Sucks. I tried and looked all over. No dice